# Fixed width and flexible count of columns with HighCharts / HighStock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighStocks and here is little example to show what i mean:
http://goo.gl/m90FGh

I wanna use those columns also for navigation(to click) so i want to have fixed width for them and with disabled grouping. The issue is when i'm trying to resize the chart (e.g. browser window is smaller). If i disable grouping and set fixed width it will create the same count of cols on the screen but those are overlapping each other. I would like to resize chart, keep columns without overlap and set another "zoom/range" in navigation/minichart to display smaller number of columns with the same width. It's about constant width & space between the columns. Is it somehow possible?

**UPDATE:**
I tried this solution: http://goo.gl/ojmsFN
It works but only if i **shrink** the screen/browser, not if i try to expand it again. The range stays still the same in this case, i don't know why.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: `plotOptions.column.maxPointWidth`

Comment: Hi, please post a minimum working example that shows the issue so that others can help you with a solution.

Comment: it does not solve the issue - it will not prevent from overlapping, It's for opposite issue when you don't want to have too wide columns, but i have fixed width.

Comment: The minimum (non)working example is already a part of the question - [link](http://goo.gl/m90FGh)

Comment: Yes you should set maxPointWidth to your desired width. It will draw the chart with your desired width whenever possible otherwise it reduce the bar's width to avoid the overlapping.

Comment: That's it, i need fixed width (due to easy navigation), not reduced bar's width - i need reduced bar count if needed. But thanks for suggestion

Comment: Have you tried to use [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) instead of pointWidth?

Comment: When window is expanding `currentRange` will be greater than difference between `max` and `min` - axis extremes, so you could call `setExtremes` ([AIP](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)) with new `min` calculated from `max` and `currentRange`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zc8csr0h/5/

Comment: You're right. Your solution works for me! Thanks! In the meantime I also found similar solution for range issue here - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291715/change-range-in-highstock-dynamically)