# jQuery datepicker with Highstocks / Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, highcharts, datepicker

How can I get a working jQuery datepicker with highcharts rangeselector?

This fiddle is an old example (from a highcharts author) which has the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/

Changing the end date will reset the start date to the beginning of the data.

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }}]

        }, function(chart) {

            // apply the date pickers
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
            }, 0)
        });
    });


    // Set the datepicker's date format
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            this.onchange();
            this.onblur();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This issue appears to be specific to the latest version (5.0.0) of highcharts/highstock. If I point to a specific older version (4.2.2) then the issue goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set extremes once a date is selected, using your onSelect event and removing this.onchange().

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes($('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').datepicker("getDate").getTime(), $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(1)').datepicker("getDate").getTime()); 
            //this.onchange();
            this.onblur();
        }
    });
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/542/

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this will help

[Change range in Highstock dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291715/change-range-in-highstock-dynamically)

I be able to update configuration of the displayed chart on the fly by accessing axis objects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I would really prefer to utilize the built in rangeSelector, but this is a good work around if I get forced to a version of highstock which doesn't work correctly.